# Verifying and passing around std::variant<> contents using parameter packs

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, variant

I am working on a snippet of code which will automatically check the types contained inside of `std::variant`s and call a function from it's subclass accordingly with the types extracted. I worked out a somewhat limited version of what I'd like to do:

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

using atom = std::variant<std::string, int, double>;

class callable {
    public:
        virtual atom eval(std::vector<atom> args) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct name {
    static const char * get() {
        return typeid(T).name();
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct is_optional : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_optional<std::optional<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<int N, typename... Ts> using pack_n =
    typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;

template <int N, typename... T>
void check(std::vector<atom> v) {
    if constexpr(!is_optional<pack_n<N, T...>>::value)
        if(v.size() != N)
            throw std::runtime_error("Wrong number of arguments to " + std::string(name<pack_n<N, T...>>::get()) + ", got " + std::to_string(v.size()));
        else {
            if(!std::holds_alternative<pack_n<N, T...>>(v[N]))
                throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Wrong type in argument ") + std::to_string(N) + name<pack_n<N, T...>>::get() + std::string(", got ") + std::to_string(v[N].index()));
            if constexpr(N > 0)
                check<N-1, T...>(v);
        }
    else {
        if (!std::holds_alternative<typename pack_n<N, T...>::value_type>(v[N]))
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Wrong type in argument ") + std::to_string(N) + name<pack_n<N, T...>>::get() + std::string(", got ") + std::to_string(v[N].index()));
        if constexpr(N > 0)
            check<N-1, T...>(v);
    }
}

template <typename... V>
class closure : public callable {
    public:
        virtual atom apply(V...);

        atom eval(std::vector<atom> args) override {
            check<sizeof...(V) - 1, V...>(args);
            return eval_impl(args, std::index_sequence_for<V...>{});
        }
    private:
        template<typename T>
        T get(atom a) {
            if constexpr(!is_optional<T>::value)
                return std::get<T>(a);
            else
                return std::optional(std::get<T>(a));
        }

        template<std::size_t... I>
        atom eval_impl(std::vector<atom> &args, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
          return apply(get<pack_n<I, V...>>(args[I])...);
        } 
};

class add : public closure<
    int, double, double, std::optional<int>
> {
    atom apply(int z, double a, double b, std::optional<int> c) {
        return a + b + *c;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    add f{ };
    std::vector<atom> v;
    v.push_back((int) 3);
    v.push_back((double) 5);
    v.push_back((double) 5);
    v.push_back((int) 3);
    std::cout << "ok?" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<double>(f.eval(v));
    std::cout << "ok?" << std::endl;
}
```

The desired behaviour is that the `apply` method from the subclass (`add::apply`)  is called with arguments unpacked from a variant, or the code throws an exception in case the types don't match. Additionally, `std::optional` and `std::variant` should be supported, so that the `apply` function can take optional arguments or specify that it accepts multiple kinds of arguments.

I've implemented the basic skeleton, and most of the `std::optional` part, but I'm still struggling to tie it all together with `std::variant`. I am not sure how to accomplish the following with C++ template metaprogramming:

- In `eval_impl`, allow input vectors of a different length than parameter packs, to properly allow `std::optional` arguments.
- The code currently doesn't compile for a reason I can't track down.
- How to support `std::variant`s in arguments.
- Whether it would be possible to have the `apply` function's parameters used for the template, so that i don't have to type the same thing multiple times.
- Is it possible to accomplish this thing in a cleaner way

To clarify, I expect the `std::variant`s for `apply` functions to allow either of the types, so for example the following function:

```cpp
atom apply(int z, double a, double b, std::optional<int> c, std::variant<int, double> d);
```

Could be called with the last argument being either an `int` or a `double`.

Comment: Are you implementing `std::visit`? Even if I read your post three times, I have no idea what you want to achieve. For my it sounds like an XY problem!

Comment: I am not implementing `std::visit`. I want to write a bit of code that automatically checks the types inside of `std::variant`s and calls the function with the values taken out of them. I need it for my programming language, where `atom` signifies a data type.
There will be, of course, many implementations of `callable`, so such a maneuver could make the code cleaner and more concise. If not that, I'd have to extract and verify `std::variant` contents each and every time myself inside the implementation - probably more than 300-400 times in the entire codebase.

Comment: "I want to write a bit of code that automatically checks the types inside of std::variants and calls the function with the values taken out of them." That is exactly std::visit. Maybe you want that std::visit calls only of some var types are storesd, but that can be implemented inside the templated method which is given to std::visit... still no idea what you want to achieve... sorry

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, `std::visit` might help you:

```cpp
template <typename... V>
class closure : public callable {
public:
    virtual atom apply(V...) = 0;

    atom eval(const std::vector<atom>& v) override
    {
        if (v.size() != sizeof...(V))
            throw std::runtime_error("Wrong number of arguments, expected" + std::to_string(sizeof...(V)) + ", got " + std::to_string(v.size()));

        return eval_impl(v, std::index_sequence_for<V...>{});
    }
private:
    template<std::size_t... Is>
    atom eval_impl(const std::vector<atom>& v, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        auto visitor = overloaded {
           [this](auto... args) -> decltype(this->apply(args...)) { return this->apply(args...); },
           [](auto... args) -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_invocable_v<decltype(&closure::apply), closure*, decltype(args)...>, atom> { throw "bad argument"; }
        };
        return std::visit(visitor , v[Is]...);
    } 
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1e280860cd817d5)